# Inkscape Blurry Image

Tags: inkscape

I need to embed a jpg image into a pdf, but the output result appears with blurry image, I use these settings for importing

[image]

and these for exporting

[image]

and this is the result.

[image]

Comment: See this for how to best scale something like a QR code without blurring - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/47163/115385

Answer (score 1):

Your image is 450x747 and you use 300dpi, so you have pixels enough to fill 1,5inch x 2,49inch which is obviously not the case with your PDF. Screen dpi is usually around 72, so you can try importing the images with 72dpi. If you have a hi-res version, then you can set higher dpi.

Comment: Changing the dpi isn't going to change the number of pixels available. If the only option is raster, then to get larger image you need… a larger image.

Comment: @Komental Even with importing/exporting using 72dpi I get the same problem. That image is issued from a government website with QR/Barcode to be scanned at police checkpoints, so I can't get another one with higher resolution.

Comment: @Tetsujin The image looks fine with image viewer (at the left), but when I embed it inside a pdf using Inkscape it becomes blurry in the exported pdf (at the right).

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode - Tetsujin and Komental are correct here. Changing the dpi in the PDF settings will not give you sharper images, or a higher resolution image. When I try this, a raster image in Inkscape exported as PDF looks [exactly the same quality](https://imgur.com/a/Tn6cwMV) in the PDF. If you want as a sharper image you'll need a higher resolution image.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode The real reason the image is blurry is because there is some resizing going on. Set all dpi fields to 72 and it should be fine for screens. Your jpeg looks fine on the screen and it should look identical inside your pdf.